# How to patch console.error or info but leave jump urls intact for Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I saw many posts how to replace the JS console functions by others but no one leaves it intact for Firebug.

When I replace any of them, it calls my custom function but it reports the message from the very same place the new function comes from.

The goal here is to receive any of those console messages and display them somewhere else whilst I still can jump to the callee in the Firebug console.

Is this possible at all ?

Update :
for instance (PSEUDO) :

```
//keep the old one
var oriFn=console.error;

console.error=function(){
   someOtherFunc(arguments);//send to server for instance
   oriFn(arguments);
}
```

Now somewhere else I'd like to call as usual console.error('bla'); In the Firebug console, it prints my message but shows a link to the replacement code above. I want in the Firebug console the link to the callee's parent function and that's it.

Comment: Give an example of what you're doing...

Answer (score 0):

Use a function pointer. Given foo.js:

```
function foo()
 {
 console.error = console.log; //Reassign console.error
 location.hash = document.title; //Do something
 console.error("Not the mama");  //Outputs line foo.js:5
 }
```

**References**

- [How to de-anonymize your anonymous functions](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2010/05/19/how-to-de-anonymize-your-anonymous-functions/)
- [JavaScript Wikibook: Anonymous Functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions)
- [JavaScript Anonymous Functions](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/06/10/javascript-anonymous-functions.html)
- [Javascript function declarations vs function operators](http://helephant.com/2012/07/14/javascript-function-declaration-vs-expression/)